# How do I receive the specific user data from firebase using phone number not by uid?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have done phone authentication linked to my project but I am not pushing the data from android instead I have manually entered the user data in Firebase. And I want to retrieve the data from firebase using OTP verification and I just need to search the specific user data with phone number which I am entering while login. I want to show all fields to be displayed which are present in my firebase database into my android project.
I've tried many methods to receive the data but I am stuck... Please help me.
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82RYs.png)

[Authentication panal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcuDO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to logically bind your authenticated user and the data that you stored in your firebase. As per the image in your data base 'id' of the 'Users' are 1,2,.. like that. Instead of that you can use 'UID' of users as an an Id in your database. Go to your 'Authentication' section, you will see User UID against each registered user. Copy that and use as an ID while creating data in database. This will help you to get the data with reference like Users\. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But I have my firebase database linked with the google sheets. Whenever I entered the data in Google sheets it automatically inserts in the Firebase database and generated a ID based on the serial number which I have in Google sheets.

Comment: In that case you can have an attribute to hold User UID. And then while you are searching first you can use `orderByChild' on same attribute and 'equalTo' method with User UI to get the right 'User' Data.